# calabash-android: interact with status bar

Tags: android, statusbar, calabash

I want to write a test that detects that a notification with a specific text is visible in the status bar. So far I tried to use the `swipe` action to pull down the notifications drawer. Sadly, swiping only works to the left and right, not down. I also tried to use the `drag` action to pull down the notification drawer.

Comment: As far as I know Calabash only effects to the given application events  not for the Phone OS events. You can't check any events that beyond the App using calabash.

Comment: As @chathura said, this is not possible. You would probably want to write a unit test to cover this case.

Answer (score 3):

I have a need to do something like this. In this case, i'm sending a PUSH notification in Appboy and want to check that we got it.
First, I create a unique message so it can't be confused with other messages:

```
unique = Time.now.to_i
push_automation_message = "PUSH Automation Msg: #{unique}"
```

then...

```
Then(/^I will see the push notification on Android$/) do
  output = `adb shell dumpsys notification` # dumps information about the status of the notification system service
  expect(output).to include push_automation_message
end
```

This solution is not ideal but it's an MVP until i have the instrumentation to check the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I just published an article on this: https://techblog.badoo.com/blog/2015/06/01/testing-android-notifications-with-calabash/

In summary, we're using 'adb shell uiautomator dump' to get a list of views on the screen, xpath to interrogate their contents, and 'adb shell input swipe' or 'adb shell input tap' to interact with them.

It's a bit clunky, but it works.